# Mser Regions to surf and surf to Mser regions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst, mser

I am using matlab `detectMSERFeatures` to detect mser regions (in between two images). After that I am using surf to find out the the corresponding mser pair in the images. The function `matchFeatures` returns the pairs of points (x,y).

My question is how to get the corresponding mser regions back using these points? 
I mean the regions corresponding to the points detected by surf? 
Please help.